# ListTile onTap: Need to Check JWT in Secure Storage and Then Proceed with Named Page Navigation

Tags: flutter, jwt, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-secure-storage

New to Flutter, and I'm stumped on how to proceed with my App.

My user has already been authenticated via an API call, and the user's JWT is already stored in Flutter Secure Storage (I have verified that the token can be read from storage).

I would like to read the token from storage (before changing routes) to make sure that it hasn't expired. If the token has expired, I'd like to route the user back to the login page using a named route `'/'`. If the token hasn't expired, I'd like to route the user to a named route called `'/devices'`.

I'm using the ListTile's `onTap;` to call an inline `FutureBuilder` where my `future:` is `secureStorage.readSecureData('jwt'),`. This is working fine.

ListTile:

```
ListTile _tile(String title, int pid) => ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(Icons.cloud_download_outlined, color: customGreen),
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: globalTheme.textTheme.headline3,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        'Property ID: ' + pid.toString(),
        style: globalTheme.textTheme.caption,
      ),
      onTap: () => FutureBuilder(
        future: secureStorage.readSecureData('jwt'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          if (snapshot.data != '') {
            var propertyInfo = {'pid': pid, 'propertyName': title};
            var jwt = snapshot.data.toString().split('.');
            if (jwt.length != 3) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
            } else {
              var payload = json.decode(
                  ascii.decode(base64.decode(base64.normalize(jwt[1]))));
              if (DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(payload['exp'] * 1000)
                  .isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushNamed('/devices', arguments: propertyInfo);
              } else {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
              }
            }
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
          }
          throw Exception('Error: builder is null');
        },
      ),
    );
```

My problem is that my code stops on my `builder:`. I've use the debugger to step through the code and have found that it simply won't continue past this line of code. No error is indicated.

Is this a type problem, or maybe I'm using FutureBuilder incorrectly?

EDIT 4/13/22:

I'm using the following `class` to read data from secure storage.

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  Future<void> writeSecureData(String key, String value) async {
    await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
  }

  Future<String?> readSecureData(String key) async {
    var readData = await storage.read(key: key);
    print('KEY: $key, JWT: $readData');
    return readData;
  }

  Future<void> deleteSecureData(String key) async {
    await storage.delete(key: key);
  }
}
```

I noticed that this class is returning `Future<String?>` as my future, but my FutureBuilder is expecting a `<String?>`. I am using `async` and `await` to read the data from storage so I expected to return `jwt` as a `String` (and it is a string when I print it in the class) but that is apparently not the case when I return it.

```
onTap: () {
        var jwt = secureStorage.readSecureData('jwt');
        print('JWT: $jwt');
      },
```

The above yields:

```
flutter: JWT: Instance of 'Future<String?>'
flutter: KEY: jwt, JWT: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoicmZyZWkiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDk4MjM0NzcsImV4cCI6MTY0OTgyMzU5N30.SiM5sXoqqWtOddLTCsBbdgnNBKSEFVSa8k2gZxg_Fhk
```

EDIT 4/13/22:

I found a solution. In addition to reading secure storage asynchronously, I also make my call to my secure routing `class` asynchronous like this:

```
onTap: () async {
  var jwt = await secureStorage.readSecureData('jwt');
  var propertyInfo = {'pid': pid, 'propertyName': title};
  print(jwt);
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/devices', arguments: propertyInfo);
},
```

Now I have access to my token. Note that `FutureBuilder` is no longer needed. Removal of `FutureBuilder`, however, also removes `BuildContext` which is needed for named routing. To overcome this problem, I pass the build `context` from `ListView` to `ListTile`.

With access to both of these items, I can finally write the logic I need for gated routing and then use named routing to route the user accordingly.